# SSRS parameter defaults to NULL (All) even though no default value is set

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a SSRS report parameter that is **incorrectly** defaulting to NULL (All), when I have the *'No default value'* option selected.  The parameter uses a stored procedure to load available values, and there are several values in my parameter drop-down-box.

[image: Paramater Properties]
[image: No Default Parameter Selected]

When I view my report in preview mode or on the SSRS poral, my parameter is automatically set to All (NULL).  What would make this happen?

The XML code shows no default values either:

```
<ReportParameters>
<ReportParameter Name="[My Parameter Name]">
  <DataType>Integer</DataType>
  <Nullable>true</Nullable>
  <Prompt>My Parameter</Prompt>
  <ValidValues>
    <DataSetReference>
      <DataSetName>MyDataSet</DataSetName>
      <ValueField>MyParameterID</ValueField>
      <LabelField>MyParameterName</LabelField>
    </DataSetReference>
  </ValidValues>
</ReportParameter>
```

Comment: This happens in Design/Preview, but when pushed to the SSRS Portal, the Null parameters will not be set to Null.

Comment: Thank you for your response @WEI_DBA.  I pushed my change to the SSRS portal and the parameter is still beings set to NULL.

Comment: Just for sake of it could you check if that value is checked in the parameters pane in ssrs manager. Make sure it is not stuck - checked but disabled. You can also delete the report in the ssrs manager and redeploy to see if your parameters are refreshed correctly.

Comment: @RossBush - Could you explain what you mean? I have no default selected for my parameter when I open the file in SQL Server Report Builder or in Visual Studio.  I have a screenshot of the parameter properties pane.

Comment: I have had some weird behavior while doing something that seemed straightforward but did not work while designing reports. In edge case situations clearing the old rdl file in the ssrs manager and redeploying the report solved my strange parameter problem. I cant say it will fix your problem, however, it could be something you could easily rule out.

Comment: As others have said, redeploying might help. Certainly in older version of SSRS (2008 definitely) the default parameter values are not overwritten when a report is updated (re-deployed). If I ever have to change defaults for a report, I always delete the report from the server and redeploy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As some users stated in the comments, you must delete and redeploy the report to update parameter defaults.  According to Microsoft this is a known issue:

> Parameter defaults do not get updated when re-deploying existing
>   reports. These either have to be updated manually or the reports
>   deleted and re-deployed. The latter regenerates all report ID's
>   (GUID's) and makes traking usage from the ExecutionLog more difficult.