# Default values updating to null for all date parameters in SSRS instead of just selected ones

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2019, reportbuilder

I am trying to updated the default value for two of my date parameters in a report.  I allow null values for all my date parameters and want to default two of the date parameters to null.

Below is a screen shot from the parameters property window in my Visual Studio 2019 SSRS project which reflects my update.  The Sales dates should not have a default value but the event dates should have a default of null.

[image]

I have looked at the info in this entry about needing to delete the report from the server to have the default values update correctly: [SSRS parameter defaults to NULL (All) even though no default value is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40750159/ssrs-parameter-defaults-to-null-all-even-though-no-default-value-is-set)

So I navigated to our ssrs web portal http://XXXXXXX/Reports/browse/XXXXXXX.  This is the same SSRS instance my Visual Studio project is configured for.  Here I see an entry for each of the reports in my project.  I delete the report whose default values I want to update.  I refresh my browser to verify the report has been deleted.  At this point I have tried simply starting the visual studio project which pushes the reports up to the SSRS server and also manually uploading the rdl file to the server from the portal itself.  After doing either of these, I refresh my browser and I now see the previously deleted report again.  Great-  However, when I select the 'new' report on the server, and open it in Microsoft Report Builder (so I can see the parameter default values) I see it has set BOTH dates to default to null instead of just the one I wanted.

[image]

Any idea why this is happening and how I can fix it?  I have verified the RDL file I am uploading from my machine only has a default value specified to Event_Date parameter.  I tried cleaning the project and removing the bin folder and it still did not work.

If I make the changed to the RDL file on the server via Report Builder, it seems to work.  However, I really need to have my VS 2019 project work correctly also as that is linked to our devops instance.

Comment: what if you renamed your RDL and upload the newly named report? Does that make any difference. Can't say I've ever come across this after many years using SSRS.

Comment: @Harry - I have not tried that yet but I can and I will post an update

Comment: @Harry  - If I rename the report - the first publish seems to be OK - but then after that I am in the same situation